# oracle table select with indexing becoming slower in first execution and after database cache clear

Tags: oracle, indexing

I've created couple of indexes along with primary key index on my table and when I ran my select query which is having joins and other stuff is taking about 30 sec to display the result for the very first time.

But after first execution, when I ran the query again second time it's giving me the result in below 2 sec and it always same for subsequent executions.

When I check online somewhere I found that execution is faster because of index database caching, so I cleared the database cache using `alter system flush buffer_cache;` then again my query taking 30 sec to display the result for the first time and second time execution onwards again taking only 2 sec time to display the result.

I'm new to this indexing and is this the way indexing will work or do I have any other ways to work my query which will display the results in 2 sec all the time.

Comment: You'd need to post more information (the query, query plan, and data model for starters along with some sense of the size of the tables).  If you're aggregating tens of thousands of rows, it may make sense that it would take 30 seconds.  If you're fetching a single row, 2 seconds is probably excessive.

Comment: Currently my table having 10M records and as said above for the first time execution only taking 30sec time but second time execution taking below 2 sec for the subsequent Id's

Comment: If you're fetching a single row of data, 2 seconds is extremely poor performance.  If you're aggregating tens of thousands of rows from that 10 million row table, 2 seconds is decent performance.

Comment: Yes. My query which includes aggregating rows and calling custom functions and so many case statements etc... For a given Id it'll fetch the records by doing all the said manipulations and ideally on an average it'll fetch minimum 10 records for a given Id. The problem is, when I tested my query by 10 times with the 10 different input Id's and for the first Id only it's taking 30 sec time to fetch the records and for the other 9 Id's it's taking only 2 sec to fetch the records. Am I missing anything here..? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ed's answer on the function of the buffer cache explains why you get different performance depending on what data happens to be in the cache.  The way you describe your query, however, it isn't obvious to me whether either warm or cold cache performance is reasonable (i.e. you may simply be missing an index or something else that would solve the problem by eliminating most of the need for logical I/O which would, in turn, substantially reduce your dependence on what data is in cache).

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with indexing or index caching.  It has everything to do with buffer caching, which you are clearing.  Whenever a query is executed, oracle will check the buffer cache to see if what is needed is already in the cache. If it is found in the cache, he can avoid an expensive physical read from disk.  If not found in the cache, it is read from disk (slow, expensive) and placed in the cache.  The next time the data is needed, it is simply pulled from the cache (fast).  But when you clear the cache, you force it back to a physical disk read.  Quit flushing the buffer cache, and the database will 'stabelize' with a normal 'working set' of cached data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Currently my table having about 10M records and when I fetch the records with different id's (primary key) I'm getting the response quickly for all the different Id's and for the first ID only it's taking 30 sec time and for the next Id's fetching the records with in 2 sec.

Comment: As per your response I understood that for every new request will it create buffer cache? for my case new buffer cache for every unique Id request will create a new buffer or cache will be created on the table schema?

Comment: I tested my query with the 10 different input Id's and for the first Id only it's taking 30 sec time to fetch the records and for the other 9 Id's it's taking only 2 sec to fetch the records. Am I missing anything here..? Thanks Again.

Comment: NO. It does not create a buffer cache for each request.  There is one buffer cache in the SGA.  The result of all queries ends up in the buffer cache.  That's why a second query of the same data will get its data from the cache instead of issuing another disk read. And any data that is in the cache is available to any query from any session.  Also, what's in the cache is whole blocks, not just individual rows.  So rows your query needed may bring along rows (in the same blocks) that might be needed by other queries.  Looks like you need to spend some quality time in the Concepts manual.

Comment: Suppose my first query with id 1 brings the data from row 1400000 to 1400010 and my second id 2 brings the data from row 3200000 to 3200010, for Id 3 row 5500000 to 5500010. For each time fetching the data from table rows varies from different range, so my Id 1 fetches the rows in 30 sec and Id 2 and 3 fetches rows in below 2 sec. Is this the same way how the cache will work as you explained above. Thanks for your patience. Note: I've created a index with the columns that were there in the select query.

Comment: The smallest unit of I/O (for oracle) is a 'block'.  A block contains several rows.  When oracle identifies a row that is needed to satisfy a query, it asks the OS for the entire block, when is then placed in the buffer cache. If that query or any other query from any other session ... even some future sessions .. needs any row that is already in the buffer cache, then it is retreived from the buffer cache and the physical read from the file is avoided.